# How to find when function is increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

When is the function defined by $f(x)=x^2+e^{-2x}$ increasing?  I know you have to take the derivative and use certain values of $x$, but I am confused on how to do this particular problem, and I would love it if any could help. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: A differentiable function (such as this one) is increasing when its derivative is positive (and decreasing when its derivative is negative).  Can you figure out when the derivative of $f$ is positive?

Comment: is the derivative 2x + e^-2x?

Comment: No it's not, see answer below. The minus two is there because we are taking the derivative of a composed function.

Answer (score 2):

First take the derivative:

$f'(x)=2x-2e^{-2x}$

Now consider the values when the derivative is equal to 0:

$2x-2e^{-2x}=0$

Now the function is increasing whenever $f'(x)$ is positive, and decreasing when it is negative. I.e., $f$ is increasing when:
\begin{align*}
2x &> 2e^{-2x}\\
x &> e^{-2x}\\
\ln(x) &> -2x
\end{align*}

As @CommonerG says below, you can compute a decimal approximation to this root.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x}=-2e^{-2x}+2x$

Thus, the function is increasing when:

$2x>2e^{-2x}$

$x>\frac{1}{e^{2x}}$

A computational approach to solving this inequality provides the condition:

$x>.426$